# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 427 (char 426)

Tags: python, json

I`m trying to upload a video on youtube via a script, but when I execute the script I get this error. The json file is working as I tested it with another script that does the same thing in a different way.I tried everything this is my last chance or I will give up on this script.
If you need more details please let me know, I appreciate your effort!

## This is the error I get:

```
 Extra data: line 1 column 427 (char 426)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "publisher/botTest.py", line 54, in <module>
     youtubeService.uploadVideoToYouTube(config)
   File "/root/publisher/core/services/youtube.py", line 202, in uploadVideoToYouTube
     youtube = getAuthenticatedService(CREDENTIALS_FILE)

   File "/root/publisher/core/services/youtube.py", line 69, in getAuthenticatedService

     flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES,redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py",
     line 172, in from_client_secrets_file
     client_config = json.load(json_file)

   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
     parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
     return _default_decoder.decode(s)

   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
     raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
 json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 427 (char 426)
```

line 202 form youtube.py:

```
def uploadVideoToYouTube(config):   
    CREDENTIALS_FILE = constants.SECRETS_ROOT_LOCATION + config['channel'][1] + '/' +
    constants.YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_CREDENTIALS_FILE_NAME

    if os.path.isfile(CREDENTIALS_FILE):
        youtube = getAuthenticatedServiceFromStorage(CREDENTIALS_FILE)
        print(os.path.isfile(CREDENTIALS_FILE))
        print(CREDENTIALS_FILE)   else:
        os.makedirs(constants.SECRETS_ROOT_LOCATION + config['channel'][1])
        youtube = getAuthenticatedService(CREDENTIALS_FILE)
```

line 69 in youtube.py:

```
# Authorize the request and store authorization credentials. Used to
# generate first auth token. Only needs to happen once.

def getAuthenticatedService(CREDENTIALS_FILE):

    flow =InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES,
    redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')   
    auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')   
    print('Please go to this URL: {}'.format(auth_url))

    code = input('Enter the authorization code: ')   
    credentials = flow.fetch_token(code=code)
    saveCredentials(CREDENTIALS_FILE, credentials)

    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = flow.credentials)
```

Comment: "The json file is working as I tested it with another script" => well, your test is wring one way or another then, because the errors is quite clear: the credential file _used by this script_ is NOT valid json, period.

Comment: i changed the credential file multiple times, and as i said I tested all of them on another script that uploads videos to youtube, but doesn`t work, I even split the json file into 2 files that contain only the client ID and client secret,but I get an error that tels me that the file needs to be str not bytes